# How can I override remove method for Set?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the remove method for Set but it doesn't work when I test it. Am I doing it wrong? the size doesn't reduce after I remove the element.

```
public class MySet<T> implements Set<T> {

  private T[] arrayB;
  private int elements;

  @Override
  public boolean remove(Object f) {
      T h = (T) f;
      for (T z : arrayB) {
          if(z == h) {
              z = null;
          }
      }
      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int size() {
      int count = 0;
      for(int arr = 0; arr < arrayB.length; arr++){
          if(arrayB[arr] != null) {
              count++;
          }
      }
      return count;
  }
```

The test code is:

```
MySet<Integer> ints = new MySet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        ints.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 2) {
        ints.remove(i);
    }   
}
```

Comment: In your `remove()`, you need to use `equals()` instead of `==`. Next, you need to set array indices to `null`, not just the temporary variable `z`.

Comment: I get NullPointerException error when I use equals method. I try to override it but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `size` method relies on whether the element is `null` to decide whether to count it.  Assuming that you are attempting to place a `null` in the array, you're doing it wrong.  All you've done is assign `null` to `z`, which is just a local variable.  The array is not changed.

You must use a traditional for loop and use an array access expression to assign `null` to the array element.  You'll also want to call `equals` instead of using `==` to find the element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] != null && array[i].equals(h))
    {
        array[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Depending on whether you want to remove *all* elements that match, or just the first one, you may consider adding a `break` statement inside the `if`.

Comment: Suggestion: You can skip the null check and write the equals backward: `h.equals(array[i])`

Comment: @NayukiMinase What if `h` is `null`?

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.